# Jewish woman marrying a Ben Noah: Halahik consequences

Tags: intermarriage

I would like to know the Halahick consequences of a Jewish woman cohabiting with a non-idolatrous goy or Ben Noah.

Reading some parts in the Talmud, I understood that they would not be considered married, therefore the woman could marry a Jew without requiring a Get. And that the off-spring would be considered "Pasul". 
Other than that I do not see other consequences.
What does it mean that someone is "pasul" anyway?

Comment: Are you limiting yourself to legal consequences in this world? If someone is sinning that's a consequence on its own!

Comment: It's a violation of halacha, I think she may be considered a zonah permanently from this

Comment: Pasul means that the offspring is defective in some way, and people would stay away from intermarrying with the family (similar to what we do with a mamzer)!

Comment: I meant consequences in halacha. I understand "legal consequences" depending on the state and, at least, in Western countries there is no crime committed. Therefor, I mean only in the Jewish law consequences.

Comment: SAH: is zonah an halachik status or just a social estigma as a result of people relating to this woman.

Comment: are these opinions? Or have real references to Halacha?

Comment: Yes. Zonah is an Halachic status, since a Kohen may not marry one (Vayikra 21:7). whether she is one, see Yevamot 61ab.

Comment: Noa if you want other people to see your comments in their inbox you need to add this @ before their name. For instance SAH will not be aware of your comments unless you write @SAH.

Comment: @Noa Consult a rabbi about whether a non-Jew's marrying or cohabiting a Jewish woman is in violation of the 7 Noahide Laws. I am quite sure it is. You would also be causing her to do the sin of z'nus which is prohibited by the Torah.